# Как сделать вывод с ограничением в OpenCart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Добрый день!Работаю с OpenCart, и не знаю как воплотить свою идею.
У нас есть 2 поля в админке, куда мы вводим слова:

```
<?php echo $price_en; ?>
<?php echo $price_ru ?>
```

Нужно чтоб строка

```
<?php echo $price_en; ?> - работала в английской версии сайта
а строка
<?php echo $price_ru; ?> - работала в русской версии сайта
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:
В контроллере продукта `catalog/controller/product/product.php` добавляем переменную, в которой будет код текущего языка, для проверки условием в шаблоне `$lng = $this->language->get('code');`
А в шаблоне продукта `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` делаем условие:

```
<?php if ($lng = 'en') { ?>
        <?php echo $price_en; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php echo $price_ru; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```